# PowerShell script not putting data to .CSV

Tags: windows, powershell

I am building a script to get drive space data. The script completes without error and creates the excel document however, the file size is 0 kb without any categories.  I cant figure out what is going wrong.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
$OldReports = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)

Get-ChildItem C:\myscripts\*.* | `
Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -le $OldReports} | `
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$LogDate = get-date -f yyyyMMddhhmm

$File = Get-Content -Path C:\myscripts\servers1.txt

$DiskReport = ForEach ($Servernames in ($File)) 

{Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk <#-Credential $RunAccount#> `
-ComputerName $Servernames -Filter "Drivetype=3" `
-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 

Where-Object {   ($_.freespace/$_.size) -le '0.1'}

} 

$DiskReport | 

Select-Object @{Label = "Server Name";Expression = {$_.SystemName}},
@{Label = "Drive Letter";Expression = {$_.DeviceID}},
@{Label = "Total Capacity (GB)";Expression = {"{0:N1}" -f( $_.Size /     1gb)}},
@{Label = "Free Space (GB)";Expression = {"{0:N1}" -f( $_.Freespace / 1gb ) }},
@{Label = 'Free Space (%)'; Expression = {"{0:P0}" -f       ($_.freespace/$_.size)}} |

Export-Csv -path "C:\MyScripts\DiskReport_$logDate.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Does the file it pulls the servers from need to be a specific format?  As of now I just have the machine name.domain

Comment: Is `$DIskReport` being populated with anything?

Comment: As I understand it, make a disk report for each host name in file that I have identified at $file am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: Yes, that loooks like what it's trying to do. I am asking what actually happens.

Comment: Well, when the script runs I dont get any errors, it creates an excel document but it is blank.  I have put just the hostnames, just the IP's with the same results.

Comment: It sounds like `$DiskReport` is empty. Take out the `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` and see what happens. EIther that's failing (and returning nothing) or the where-object filter is filtering everything out.

Comment: Are you sure you have a disk with less than 10% free space? I get results when I increase the '0.1' value. Well, $DiskReport gets data.

Comment: Along with the other suggestions, you can use dot sourcing to check the contents of the variables after the script is finished running. For example: `. c:\scripts\yourscript.ps1` Then `$DiskReport | FL`.

Comment: I changed the size, still nothing in report.